# Manipulating configurable products in Magento

Tags: magento

I already know how to create configurable products by following the instructions from [here](http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/tutorial-creating-a-configurable-product/) and it works but my question is, is it possible to just add 1 configurable attribute and add it to all product pages instead of creating multiple products for 1 configurable product? It might be tedious if there are a lot of options for 1 product.

Comment: How would you then keep a track of the inventory for a particular type of configurable product with those attributes??

Comment: I think the question is more about what the configurable products stand for.

Their main function is to create a group of products with similar characteristics. It means, for instance, a pair of shoes. We can have many simples with different sizes, but same color, style and so on. The configurable one in this case is gonna but all of them available for the user once it goes to the Product Page. 

Thinking this way, yes, you have to create 1 config one for each group of products you want

Comment: I was just hoping there was a faster way of handling this because there are a lot of products on the store with options. Anyway, thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a simple product with custom options!